# sql oracle in() clause

Tags: sql, oracle, if-statement

Is it possible to use `in()` clause in `case.. when ...the` construction in  sql query condition expression.

im my case the query is very long:

```
select  r.insurance_package_id,r.name,
       max(case r.insurance_package_id when 6 then r.name  
                                       when 7 then r.name  
                                       when 8 then r.name  
                                       when 9 then r.name  
                                       when 10 then r.name  
                                       when 11 then r.name  
                                       when 12 then r.name  
                                       when 14 then r.name    
                                       when 42 then r.name    
                                       when 44 then r.name  
                                       when 7 then r.name  

                 end) CPI_Life
```

there are about 200 id supposed to be used in condition expression: thus, the query would be very brut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible .Please refer the below snippet

```
SELECT r.insurance_package_id
    ,r.NAME
    ,max(CASE 
            WHEN r.insurance_package_id IN (
                    6
                    ,7
                    ,8
                    ,9
                    ,10
                    ,11
                    ,12
                    ,14
                    ,42
                    ,44
                    ,7
                    )
                THEN r.NAME
            END) CPI_Life
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can:

```
SELECT r.insurance_package_id,
       r.name,
       MAX(CASE 
             WHEN r.insurance_package_id IN (6,7,8,9,10,11,12,14,42,44,7) THEN r.name  
           END) CPI_Life
...
```

Answer (score 1):

i'll just add a link to the case documentation http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm

the key here is changing from a "simple case expressions" to a "searched case expression"